# XMGrace side menus don't work on WSL2 Windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, gui, wsl2

I have installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 with Ubuntu 20.0 LTS on a Windows 11 machine (a DELL XPS 13) and I wanted to use it to run XMGrace, the popular 2D plotting tool for the X Window System (https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/). I've correctly downloanded it it starts without problems. The problems arrive when I try to use to click in any button or using the top menu bar: I can click on the top menu and it regularly open the dedicated side menu, but then, if I click on any options isde the side menu, the side menu itself closes and does nothing esle. As instance, if I click on *File*(see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmXCX.png)), the side menu appears containing the option *Save*, but clicking *Save* does nothing except closing the side menu; however, I can still save my work through keyboard shortcut

I've found only a partial workaround: if I click on any point of the graph, the typical, dedicated subwindow menu opens (see picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqHlF.png)): if I keep this subwindow open, suddenly the top menu and the side menus work fine (see picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RCnA.png)). But this is very lacklusting: whenever I open side menus inside the said subwindow - which I really need to do, for example to change the colour of plot lines - they don't work, the just close as before.

Never had this problem on my previous Ubuntu Dual Boot system, may someone please help me?

I tried following this [WSL2 won't use Xming on Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1713550/wsl2-wont-use-xming-on-windows-11) , but to no avail.

Thanks to anyone who will answer.

Comment: Do you actually have Xming (or some other X server) installed for those instructions to work?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Xming and XLaunch